# make nullable Numeric up down c#

Tags: c#, winforms, numericupdown

Is there anyway to remove the 0 from the default value of 0 on the numeric up down tool in c#? I need to default to null "" if the user does not set the numeric updown tool, as it always will pass a 0 through when saved is clicked. I have tried this but with no joy

```
private void nud_HouseNumber_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    if (nud_HouseNumber.Text == "0")
    {
        nud_HouseNumber.Text = "" ;
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Strangely your attempt seems to work perfectly well for me...

Comment: @MetaColon really couldnt get it to work for the life of me, but now found a solution thanks to Ares, simple and effective.

Answer (score 2):

The Text property in a NumericUpDown Winfoms control should not be used from your code.  The MS documentation says;

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cs40s7ds(v=vs.110).aspx

> This API supports the product infrastructure and is not intended to be
> used directly from your code
>
> The Text has no affect on the appearance of the NumericUpDown control;
> therefore, it is hidden in the designer and from IntelliSense.

The controls uses a `Value` property which is of type decimal.  As such, then decimal is not nullable so you can't set this to null, or "" as you are actually trying to do in your code (this is not null!)

I would suggest that you create your own version of the control.

See also: [Windows Forms - customizing NumericUpDown to be nullable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15406322/windows-forms-customizing-numericupdown-to-be-nullable)

Comment: Ah ok, does make sense in that case. I was using the value property to access the data entered, just wasnt sure if there was a property to set it to null. But should be fine, will just deal with it in coming in as zero as the default. But creating an extension of the numeric up down class is not a bad shout actually so will give that a shot also

Comment: Another option is to just stop the user from submitting if the initial value is 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Text property. Not elegant in my opinion, but it works. For example:

```
decimal? myValue = null;
if (numericUpDown.Text != null)
    myValue = numericUpDown.Value;
```

On the contrary, to set the value would be:

```
numericUpDown.Value = myValue ?? -1;
if (numericUpDown.Value == -1)
    numericUpDown.Text = null;
```